# Using Mapfish Print v2 yaml file for Mapfish Print v3

Tags: geoserver, geoext, mapfish

I had a working Mapfish Print v2 yaml file. Is it possible to use the same in Mapfish Print v3 yaml?

My old yaml file looks like this.

```
  #===========================================================================
  # allowed DPIs
  #===========================================================================
  dpis: [72, 190, 300, 500]
  formats:
    - pdf
    - png
    - gif
  #===========================================================================
  # the allowed scales
  #===========================================================================
  scales:
    - 1000
    - 25000
    - 50000
    - 100000
    - 200000
    - 300000
    - 400000
    - 500000
    - 600000
    - 700000
    - 800000
    - 900000
    - 1000000
    - 2000000
    - 2500000
    - 3000000
    - 3500000
    - 4000000
    - 4500000
    - 5000000
    - 5500000
    - 6000000
    - 6500000
    - 7000000
    - 7500000
    - 8000000
    - 8500000
    - 9000000
    - 9500000
    - 10000000

  #===========================================================================
  # the list of allowed hostshttp://otile1.mqcdn.com
  #===========================================================================
  hosts:
  .....
```

Below is the error message that I got.

```
  Error while processing request:
  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is 
  not allowed in prolog.
```

Comment: did you try it in MapFish v3?

Comment: Yes but it shows some error message. Let me update the question to show the error message.

Comment: I just updated with the error message.